# How to properly use sklearn's cross_validate with One Hot Encoded classes?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, one-hot-encoding

I created a model to classify my 8-classes dataset and get some scores from it using MLP. To do so, I decided to use sklearn.metrics.cross_validate, using 10 folds.

The following code works fine:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, make_scorer, f1_score
import pandas as pd

def MLPClasify(sample):
    df = pd.read_csv('my_path\\my_file.csv', header=None)
    y = df[NumberOfFeatures]
    x = df.drop([NumberOfFeatures], axis=1)
    clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(27), activation='logistic', max_iter=500, alpha=0.0001, 
                        solver='adam', verbose=10, random_state=21, tol=0.000000001)
    clf.out_activation_ = 'softmax'
    scoring = {'Accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score), 'F1': make_scorer(f1_score, 
               average='weighted')}
    scores = cross_validate(clf, x, y, cv=10, scoring=scoring)
    return scores
```

Everything went ok, I was getting some accuracies around 60%. So I decided to use one hot encoding to see if I can get better results. So I wrote the following code:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, make_scorer, f1_score
import pandas as pd

def MLPClasify(sample):
    df = pd.read_csv('my_path\\my_file.csv', header=None)
    y = df[NumberOfFeatures]
    x = df.drop([NumberOfFeatures], axis=1)
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)
    onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
    integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
    onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
    y = onehot_encoded
    clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(27), activation='logistic', max_iter=500, alpha=0.0001, 
                        solver='adam', verbose=10, random_state=21, tol=0.000000001)
    clf.out_activation_ = 'softmax'
    scoring = {'Accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score), 'F1': make_scorer(f1_score, 
               average='weighted')}
    scores = cross_validate(clf, x, y, cv=10, scoring=scoring)
    return scores
```

Well, the code runs, but I get the following warning:

UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true nor predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to con
trol this behavior.
  average, "true nor predicted", 'F-score is', len(true_sum)

Also, my accuracy drops to less than 2%

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think I would consider using OHE in that situation. However, we could use more information regarding what kind of `y` data are you dealing with? Are you passing the values as integers or categories?

Comment: the y values before applying one hot encoding are categories ('A01', 'A02'...'A08').

I actually chose One Hot Encoding because I couldn't get AUC Score with categories as class labels